# Broken/missing vertical sliding window pin

Tags: windows

One of two windows in a room of my house is broken, has been since before I moved in. It will lift/slide open, but without any assistance from the spring mechanism that normally takes a lot of the weight off the user.

On closer inspection, the problem seems to be that the points where the window would rest in the spring mechanism are missing and broken on that window (missing on one side, snapped off on the other).

I cannot find a brand anywhere on the windows, including in between the glass, so I'll have to resort to seeing if anyone recognizes these parts.

So, anyone recognize these little steel bits? Even a brand on the windows would be helpful!

The 'good' side
[image: The 'good' side]

[image: The 'good' side]

The sliding component that these pins should be sitting in
[image: The sliding component that these pins should be sitting in]

The broken pin on the broken window (the other side on this window is missing outright)
[image: The broken pin on the broken window (the other side on this window is missing outright)]

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of lifetime guaranteed windows that you can’t track down parts for because the company doesn’t want you to be able to find them.

Comment: Have you pulled down the top sash and looked at the top of the sash for a nameplate?

Comment: @Tyson yeah, not a huge surprise.

Comment: @mikes There is a label up there - two values: VB397263-1, and the date of manufacture, 2010-06-22. I can't find much meaning in that first value...

Comment: @Gavin I had the same type thing in two houses now.  The moral of the story is there are probably about two window companies that actually put there name on stuff, the rest want to offer long warranties to sell windows, but you can’t find them in business a few years later.

Comment: @Gavin Take a good unit to a real machine shop and have them manufacture one for you - it will cost you a few bucks $50-$75 for the setup and first piece and probably $25 more to get 5 to 10 more pieces.  I know it sounds extreme but you might be surprised that a small shop will produce them for you. They might even have a 3-D printer to print one out.